# Manual Java compiling from terminal ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java

I am coding on a very simple school assignment and in one of the tasks i have to pass variables to as varargs from my terminal. I've tried to define the full classpath but it keeps throwing the same exception.

I have a file structure where the file i want to run is inside src/opgave1/Letters.java

```
package opgave1;

public class Letters {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        voidLetter(args);   
    }
    
    public static void voidLetter(String ... var) {
        System.out.println(var.length);
    }

}
```

Test run from projects src folder:

```
$>javac opgave1/Letters.java
$>java opgave1.Letters arg1 arg2 arg3
$ Error: Could not find or load main class opgave1.Letters
$ Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: opgave1.Letters
```

I've looked at similar issues here on stackoverflow but none of the solutions work for me.

Comment: How did you compile the code?

Comment: You need to compile the code with `javac` first, then execute the compiled code (a `.class` file) with arguments via `java`. You would normally have an IDE which does all of this for you in the background

Comment: @rouge not strictly speaking - https://www.infoq.com/articles/single-file-execution-java11/

Answer (score 0):

Compile it as follows:

```
javac -d . Letters.java
```

and run it as follows:

```
java opgave1.Letters arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Enter the following command to know more about `javac`:

```
javac
```

Note that `.` in the command means the current directory.

**Demo:**

```
[~]: cd /Users/arvind.avinash/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/src
[~/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/src]: vi Letters.java
[~/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/src]: javac -d . Letters.java
[~/Documents/workspace-spring-tool-suite-4-4.4.0.RELEASE/AdHoc/src]: java opgave1.Letters arg1 arg2 arg3
3
```

Comment: Thanks for the walkthrough. When i run the javac command from the package dir "opgave1" it creates a new folder called opgave1 and inside that folder Letters.class exist. So it should now be compiled. When i run java opgave1.Letters arg1 arg2 arg3 from the src/opgave1 path i still get the ClassNotFoundException. i've also tried to define the classpath without any luck. Any ideas?

Comment: @LukasMittunAlexanderGuldstv - `When i run the javac command from the package dir "opgave1"` - that's the root cause of the problem. If you check my answer carefully, you will find that I have run the `javac` command from `src` folder. Feel free to comment in case of any doubt/issue.

Comment: If i run ` javac -d . Letters.java ` from ./src it throws error: ` file not found: Letters.java `. The file is inside ./src/opgave1/Letters.java - if i run ` javac -d . opgave1/Letters.java ` from src it works. But `java opgave1.Letters a b c` still returns that error

Comment: It still doesn't solve it. I've passed on the task to another guy in my group im doing the assignment with. Thanks

Comment: @LukasMittunAlexanderGuldstv - Since you've already declared `package opgave1;` in `Letters.java`, you do not have to put `Letters.java` inside `./src/opgave1`. The package, `opgave1` will be automatically created by the `javac` command. Put `Letters.java` inside `./src` and use the commands as shown in the answer.